# NavigationView item selected not working.If I clicked any item then drawer menu was closing

Tags: java, android

**This is the code. Please help me. If I click any item on NavigationView then the drawer was closing.**
The app is running well but this one function is not working. When I debug this app then I saw navView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener is not called. If I click any item menu then close the drawer. How can I fix this issue? Please help me

```
 private void initView() {
    mToolbar = findViewById(R.id.dash_toolbar);
    drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer);
    navView = findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
    bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
}

private void actionBar() {
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.app_name);
    }
}

private void drawerMenu() {
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, mToolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder
            (R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_share)
            .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
            .build();

    navView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener
            (new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                // This method will trigger on item Click of navigation menu
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
                    //Check to see which item was being clicked and perform appropriate action

                    int id = menuItem.getItemId();

                    if (id == R.id.nav_home) {
                        Toast.makeText(DashboardActivity.this, "Home ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    if (id == R.id.nav_share) {
                        Toast.makeText(DashboardActivity.this, "Share message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    //Checking if the item is in checked state or not, if not make it in checked state
                    if (menuItem.isChecked()) {
                        menuItem.setChecked(false);
                    } else {
                        menuItem.setChecked(true);
                    }
                    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                    return true;
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: `implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener` ??